# UITableViewController in iOS 8 Today Extension

Tags: objective-c, ios8-today-widget

I'm trying to add UITableViewController to Today Widget, but every time I drag UITableViewController to Storyboard and run the Widget it crashes with the following error.

I've tried multiple times. I've tried it by using Table View object, but problem persists.

Note: It crashes even before loading viewDidLoad() method.

> 2015-06-06 01:19:20.569 iOSHackerToday[3202:283287] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[**NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107842c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001074dbbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010770f8ca -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 954  3
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000107d6f0b9
>   -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 338   4   UIKit                               0x0000000108241a0c
>   -[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __createViewController:withContextToken:fbsDisplays:appearanceSerializedRepresentations:legacyAppearance:traitCollection:initialInterfaceOrientation:hostAccessibilityServerPort:canShowTextServices:replyHandler:]
>   + 2216    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107738dec __invoking_** + 140  6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107738c42 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290     7   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001077c9016 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54     8   UIKit
>   0x00000001082fd01b -[_UIViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy
>   forwardInvocation:] + 222     9   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010779ff4f ***forwarding*** + 495     10  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010779fcd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120    11  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738dec **invoking_** + 140    12  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738c42 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290   13  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001077c9016 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54     14  UIKit
>   0x00000001082889f4 -[_UIQueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 319   15 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010779ff4f
>   ***forwarding*** + 495    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010779fcd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  17  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738dec **invoking_** + 140    18  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738c42 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290   19  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001077c9016 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54     20 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010779ff4f
>   ***forwarding*** + 495    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010779fcd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  22  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738dec **invoking_** + 140    23  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000107738c42 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290   24  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000109da6f16 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12  25 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109dc1964
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109daca59 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 704  27 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077aa1f9
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010776bdcb __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2043    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010776b366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470   30  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010b01ca3e GSEventRunModal + 161  31  UIKit
>   0x0000000107c3b900 UIApplicationMain + 1282   32  libxpc.dylib
>   0x000000010a0a7aec _xpc_objc_main + 453   33  libxpc.dylib
>   0x000000010a0a9e91 xpc_main + 185     34  Foundation
>   0x0000000107209ee1 service_connection_handler + 0     35  PlugInKit
>   0x0000000106ff3a82 -[PKService run] + 521     36  PlugInKit
>   0x0000000106ff3747 +[PKService main] + 55     37  PlugInKit
>   0x0000000106ff3aa6 +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 17   38 
>   libextension.dylib                  0x000000010978399d NSExtensionMain
>   + 51  39  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109df1145 start + 1    40  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

Comment: Can you share the code.

Comment: There isn't any problem with the code. It crashes as soon you add UITableViewController or Table View object to StoryBoard, even without changing/adding a single line of code.

Comment: Can you share the storyboard  screenshot?

Comment: Ok here are the images. I've created a new project, added Today Extension target. Deleted the default layout from Storyboard file and dragged in the UITableViewController.

http://imgur.com/slWCWG

and here's the error. 

http://imgur.com/KcQTr5G

Comment: First image link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the default layout and drag a new table view controller, you need to mark the new view controller as 'Intial View Controller'

[image: Mark as initial view controller]

Here's the Apple's document which explains how to do it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/SetInitialController.html

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, if you are using a custom view controller class made in swift, make sure you check the box 'Inherit Module From Target':

[image: xcode screenshot]